# Consume netTcpBinding service

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, .net-micro-framework

I am designing a service that will execute computations, which are too heavy for my device. For best performance, I want to use netTcpBinding. The MFSvcUtil tool successfully generates the code files from the provided WSDL. But I don't see any way to instantiate a proxy with netTcpBinding.

The only bindings that are available are `WS2007HttpBinding` and `CustomBinding`. Using WS2007HttpBinding would look like this (according to [this blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232761.aspx)):

```
WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding (new HttpTransportBindingConfig(new Uri("url to svc")));
m_proxy = new ProxyClass (binding, new ProtocolVersion11());
```

But I don't want to use HTTP. Which binding should I use?